# All forms of authentication are broken but local accounts at the box

Tags: centos, ssh, login, domain

I'm experiencing some domain/ssh login problems with a Centos 7.5 box.

#### Things I've checked

- The box is connected to the network
- The box has an IP
- The box is in the domain controllers list of boxes
- The box can be pinged from other boxes
- My domain account isn't locked
- firewalld and selinux are disabled
- iptables rules are set to accept all connections

#### Things I've tried

- I've cleared cached credentials with `sss_cache -E`
- checking that the box can get to the credentials with `getent passwd username`

#### Ways I've tried to log in and errors or successes

- Domain account at the login screen of gnome. (Only enter username)

  - `Sorry that didn't work. Please try again.`
  - The really strange thing is that the username resolves to the persons name in the name list after this (other domain users tried this on my box that hadn't logged into the box before)
- Local user at the login screen of gnome. (root or other users)

  - works
- SSH from other box to problem box (Domain account, root and other local accounts)

  - `permission denied, please try again`
- SSH from problem box to other box

  - works

I suspect something is wrong with the authentication service (pam.d?) but don't know how to diagnose this further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in `/var/log/secure`, and have you modified your `/etc/pam.d/`files any, or could you compare them to a working box?

Comment: Is your user or a group you’re a member of allowed in the sshd_config

Comment: @cutrightjm I'm reviewing this log now. I haven't manually changed any `/etc/pam.d` files but the script that sets up a box to join the domain uses a tool called VAS which does. I had a failure when running the script and think that left me in a bad state. I see VAS related error messages in the `/var/log/secure`

Comment: Ok so my `/etc/pam.s/sshd` file was setup to `pam_deny.so` everything. I copied over a working version of the file from another box and ssh started working again. I then had a secondary problem where the "domain users" group was renamed at some point to "Domain Users" at some point after my home directory was created. After a quick `chown "username:Domain Users" username` I'm back up and running. Thank you for the help identifying the log.